# US World of Warcraft Cataclysm activation key for EU account

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a EU WOW account, recently I purchased the Cataclysm expansion DVD.
I mistakenly got the **US** expansion DVD instead of the **EU** one, and of course the activation key doesn't work for my account.
Is there away to fix this issue? or can Blizzard support help me with it?

and what about the US game installation itself, how to make it work to connect to my EU realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can still return the Cataclysm DVD to wherever you bought it from, this is your best option.

If you already installed the US version of Cataclysm on top of your EU game client, and the game is now trying to connect to the US realms, you can fix it by opening your `realmlist.wtf` file and changing any instances of `us` to `eu`. (I'm not sure if the US installer will even work on an EU version of the client in the first place, though. I've never tried it, and can't find any info about other people that have.)

In any case, a call to Blizzard support is probably your best bet.

Comment: thanks, returning the DVD may take days, since i'm in the middle east and i purchased it from amazon-US.
I'm trying to call blizzard support, but i can't find an international number

Comment: @Ahmad You can try emailing billing@blizzard.com.

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks, i actually sent an email, but i was hoping there would be a quicker way :(

Comment: blizzard billing support replied to my email, asked for some info and replaced the key :D, I upgraded my EU account using the new key and everything worked fine.
the client itself is not a big issue, i have the EU one patched for WotLK but i thought the DVD will have the cataclysm patch, so, after all i did not use the client on the DVD and did not try the realmlist.wtf thing.

Comment: @Ahmad: Glad it worked out for you. And yeah, you won't need to install the DVD at all -- once Cataclysm is added to your account, the launcher will automatically download the expansion for you.